# How to set padding to all children elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<td style="__WHAT?__">
   <div class="generated-framework-class">
      <div class="generated-framework-class">
         <!-- ... -->
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

What should I write into the style attribute to set `padding: 0px` to all children divs. I can't set this padding directly to those divs because they are generated by an `UI-framework`. Is it possible to do strictly on css, without `JS`?

Comment: You can't. Style tags do not accept CSS selectors like that.

Comment: You would need to add the styles to a style sheet to do what you want, not inline

Comment: @Huangism well, if it's not possible....

Comment: @Paulie_D What css-selkector did you mean?

Comment: @user3663882: Probably referring to sdcr's comment.

Comment: You can't use style tags to style anything other than the element to which they are attached.

Comment: but OP probably  can use `<style>.element * {padding: 0;} </style>` or apply to the class names directly.

Comment: @sdcr But that wasn't the question. If you think he can add a style to the class names or CSS file then he wouldn't need to use style tags in the first place.

Comment: @Paulie_D agreed, i guess OP should have made it like a pure CSS question.

Comment: @user3663882 glad that helped, i guess it's the case of not able to edit the style sheet, you should mention that early.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is wrapping another div around the elements. You are able to use the CSS Selector "element element" to define the style.

```css
.whatever div {
  padding: 0;
  
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: purple;
}

.whatever div div {
  padding: 0;
  
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<td>
    <div class="whatever">
       <div class="generated-framework-class">
          <div class="generated-framework-class">
             <!-- ... -->
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), `style` is also an attribute, so you can query it by `[]`.
So `td[style*="__WHAT?__"] div` selects all the `div`s thich are descendants of element `td` with attribute `style="__WHAT__"`.

```css
td[style*="__WHAT?__"] div {
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<td style="__WHAT?__">
  <div class="generated-framework-class">
    <div class="generated-framework-class">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score -3):

To downvoters, please note that elements generated by a UI framework can have classes too...

```
//target all .generated-framework-class inside the TD
td .generated-framework-class{
     padding:0px;
}
```

Using the style attribute of an element can only style that exact element. So adding padding in the td's style attribute will only affect its own padding. Note that some CSS properties defaults values are "inherit" like `color`, using this in the style tag will color the text inside the whole td so it seems like it cascades to the other child elements, but it's not directly affecting the styling of each children.

If you do not know the classes or they are dependent on the content and cannot be predicted, you can use the children selector and/or the asterisk to target every element inside another.

```
//Use a class instead of "td" if you want to target specific elements.
td *{//Target every elements inside TD
    padding: 0;
}
td > *{//Target every direct children elements of TD
    padding: 0;
}
td div{//Target every div elements inside TD
    padding: 0;
}
td > div{//Target every direct children div of TD
    padding: 0;
}
```

Each of those selectors can have a use depending on your needs, a mix of them is also possible... I would still like to stress the fact that most UI Frameworks should be using classes and that it would be better to use those classes, but there are multiple ways to do the same thing so you are free to decide!

Comment: It would not be overriding if done correctly according to its parent... I'll give an example.